# Preloading and drawing an Image onto a canvas inside a Vue SPA doe snot work

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, canvas

I have a Vue 3 SPA where I manipulate some canvas elements. I preload my image using the function below

```
async preloadLogo () {
    return new Promise( (resolve) => {
        var logo_img_temp = new Image();
        const logo_src = require("../assets/eccc_logo.png");
        logo_img_temp.src = logo_src;
        logo_img_temp.onload = ( ) => {
            resolve(logo_img_temp)
        };
    })
},
```

In another function I try to `drawImage` the preloaded image using the code below and a context

```
var ctx = composedCnv.getContext('2d');
...
this.preloadLogo().then(
    ( img ) => {
        console.log(img instanceof HTMLImageElement,img.tagName, img); returns true IMG <img .../>
        ctx.drawImage(img, 50,50);
    }
)
```

I do not get the Image drawn even though the rest of my code works and I get the text onto the canvas. The best I could come up with is to get an error saying img is not of type HTMLImageElement which I checked to be true. Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A work around was adding an `img` to the template so it is rendered on creation and then `getElementById`.

```
<template>
...
   <img id="YOUR_ID" src="@/PATH/IMG_NAME.png" style="display: none;"/>
...
</template>
```

and then fetching it using a `const image = document.getElementById('YOUR_ID')`.